# Problem at Developing Apex batch job?

Tags: rest-api, api, batch, callout, apexrest

i have developed a REST class for to integrating salesforce with servicenow.now i'm getting the incidents created in servicenow into salesforce cases that's also working fine "BUT HOW TO WRITE A BATCH JOB" on Salesforce Cases and call it from after insert trigger.

"i have read some salesforce batch job links but little confusion how to call rest class from apex batch job and all".

in my apex rest class i'm calling all the incidents of type sftype from servicenow.
i'm encoding in endpoint url:

https://myInstance-now.com/api/now/table/incident?sysparm_fields=impact%2Cincident_state%2Cshort_description%2Csys_id%2Ccontact_type&sysparm_limit=2&u_sftype=true');

here i'm calling all the incidents from servicenow into salsforce cases.

this is my REST class

```
global with sharing class SfService {

     @future (callout=true) 
     global static void getIncident(String subject){  

        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest req =  new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();

        string text = subject;  
        req.setEndpoint('https://myinstance.service-now.com/api/now/table/incident?sysparm_fields=impact%2Cincident_state%2Cshort_description%2Csys_id%2Ccontact_type&sysparm_limit=2&u_sftype=true');

        req.setMethod('GET');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 

        String username = 'admin';
        String password = 'abcd';
        Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(username + ':' + password);
        String authorizationHeader = 'BASIC ' +
        EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
        req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);  
        res = http.send(req);
        System.debug('jsonrResult :' + res.getBody());       
        Deserialization.ResponseResult theresult1 = (Deserialization.ResponseResult)JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(),  Deserialization.ResponseResult.class);
        System.debug('Results == :' + theresult1 ); 

        List<Case> casesToUpsert = new List<Case>();        
        for(Deserialization d : theresult1.result ){

                Case c = new Case(); 
                c.Priority = d.impact;
                c.Status = d.incident_state;
                c.Subject = d.short_description;
                c.ServiceNowId__c = d.sys_id;
                c.Origin = d.contact_type;

                casesToUpsert.add(c);

        }
        system.debug('Cases to UPsert ::: ' +casesToUpsert);

        if(casesToUpsert.size()>0){
            Database.upsert(casesToUpsert,false) ;
        }

    }

}
```

anyone help to develop the apex batch job on Cases  and call it frin after insert cases so that if that batch job is running itpulling all the incidents from servicenow of type sftype into salesforce Cases.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write a batch job on any sObject. From your requirement I understood you have a trigger. From there you need to invoke a batch class and pass newly created cases to batch. You could try this.

```
trigger CaseTrigger on Case (after insert) {
    Set<Id> caseIds = trigger.newmap.keySet();
    String query = 'SELECT Id, Priority, Status, Subject, ServiceNowId__c, Origin '+
                    'FROM Case '+
                    'WHERE Id IN :caseIds';
    YourBatchClass batch = new YourBatchClass(query);//Replace YourBatchClass with name of your batch class
    database.executeBatch(batch);
}
```

Comment: global class ServiveNowBatch implements Database.Batchable, Database.AllowsCallouts{
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
String query = 'SELECT Id, Priority, Status, Subject, ServiceNowId__c, Origin FROM Case WHERE Status=1 LIMIT 50';
return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
} global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Case> scope){

}
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){ }
}

help me to develop the execute()

Comment: @shanker Modify your question what exactly you want to do and what did you try so far. After posting an answer you cannot ask others to do your work. It will not work.

Comment: @shanker if this answer resolves your current question please close it by accepting answer and post new question with what you need to do in `execute()` method.